# How can I make a custom text field with UIKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I want to create special text fields, with different background images, colors or sizes. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate, do you wish to extend `UITextField` or programatically set properties [see this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/) or use interface builder to set properties?

Comment: @TomIngram : nice link. Why don't you put it in answers?

Comment: thanks  I use this way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861527/uitextfield-border-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB, drag a View into your current view, set it's `Custom Class` to your own class (probably an UITextField subclass) and start adding your own images etc.

Answer (score 0):

Appologies in advance if my example code has errors, I have not done much cocoa/objective-c in a while but here are three approaches to your problem.

Programatically setting properties in say a `UIView`

```
@interface MYView: UIView
{
}

@implementation MYView
{
  - (void) loadView {
    UITextField * text = [[UITextField alloc] init];

    text.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);

    [text setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:30]];
    [text setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];

    [self.view addSubview:text];
  }

}
```

Through inheritance - which you can use in a view as above (maybe also use from IB)

```
@interface MYTextFied: UITextField
{
}

@implementation MYTextField
{

  - (void) init {
    self = [super init];      
    if (self != nil) {         
      [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:30]];
      [self setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
    }
    return self; 
  }

}
```

In IB just click around until you find the appropriate menu/pane or take a look at [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-interface-builder-basic-training/)