# Make a red border arround UITextfield which contains errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, validation

I am making a form in objective-c. I post all the data that I filled in, in my form to a webservice. This gives me a 200-code if everything is OK and the data is posted successfully. But it gives me a 406-code if there is something wrong. If that is the case. The JSON also contains error objects. You can see an example of the JSON over here.

```
{

    "data": {
        "status": 406,
        "message": "Not Acceptable",
        "errors": {
            "cu_email": [
                "'stefappmax.be'is no valid email!"
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

Al my textfields have the same name as in the JSON `e.g. My email-textfield calls cu_email`
Now I have this piece of code.

```
   NSDictionary* dict = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
                NSLog(@"dict: %@",dict);
                for (NSString *errorObject in [dict objectForKey:@"errors"]) {
                    NSLog(@"error name: %@",errorObject);
                }
```

This gives back all the names of the textfields that contains an error. What I want to do now is to make a red border around those textfields. I know to place a border you need to implement the quartzcore frame work and add this piece of code.

```
self.cu_email.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

But do you guys now how I can replace the cu_email with the `errorObject`?

Comment: Do you want to replace the email text with the error text or paint a red border in the field?

Comment: paint a red border around the field

Comment: You may find the solution in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5749376/1034126).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

You can access that textField property using KVC:

```
UITextField *theErrorField = (UITextField *)[self valueForKey:errorObject];
theErrorField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
theErrorField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. Do you maybe need some more details ?

Comment: @StefGeelen: did you declared property for these textfields or dynamically adding textfields ?

Comment: I declared a property for those textfields.

Comment: Oke strange, when I do theErrorField.text = @"test" it show 'test' on the fields that are containing an error.

Comment: Got it, edited my answer, you need to specify a width for border

Comment: @StefGeelen: with pleasure :)