# Changing textField border color iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, xib

I want to change **UITextField border** color. Is it possible to customize the color of border? I searched all options in `xib` but I did not found any option to change `border color`.

Comment: sorry when i searched for textfield border color change i dint found that post so i posted otherwise i would have not.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

you can use this:

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];

yourTextField.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
```

and remember to import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your .h file

You can also specify your RGB value.

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f blue:178.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor];
```

*Note: you need to set both values starting with iOS 7*

***Update for swift 2.3***

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

*OR*

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 178.0 / 255.0, green: 178.0 / 255.0, blue: 178.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
```

***Update for swift 3.1.1***

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

*OR*

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 178.0 / 255.0, green: 178.0 / 255.0, blue: 178.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on IOS7

Comment: It is only work with borderWidth . you have to give borderWidth even in iOS6. It is working fine with iOS7 also.

Comment: Struggled with this about 10mins! Finally it appears that I've not connected textField to the outlet (

Comment: happens @trickster77777 :)

Comment: It might be worth noting in the answer, that you need to set both the `borderColor` and `borderWith` in iOS 7 and iOS 8 to make the color actually change.

Comment: markField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor; - for Swift 5

Answer (score 12):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Use below code to change Textfield's border color

```
textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
textField.clipsToBounds      = YES;
```

**For SWIFT:**

```
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor;
```

Comment: txt_field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor // For Swift

Answer (score 5):

Use Quartzcore framework.
You can set the textField.layer.borderWidth, as well as borderColor:

```
tField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

for more reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749376/1554632