# How to Change Multiple UITextField Border Style and Color

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uistoryboard, uitextborderstyle

**EDIT #2**

It seems based on the responses I've gotten that I'm confusing people (and subsequently myself).  So let's try to simplify this question some -

I wish to give all TextFields in a given `ViewController` the following:

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
[[textField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

Where should I implement this and how so that it does not give me errors for the layer property (ie when I try to do this in or after `-(void)viewDidLoad` I get an error for every line stating that "Property 'layer' not found on object of type `ViewController`"?

**EDIT #1**
Full section of subclass code to assist in identifying the issue:

```
@interface InputTextField : UITextField
@end
@implementation InputTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
int margin = 5;
CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + margin, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - margin, bounds.size.height);
return inset;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
int margin = 5;
CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + margin, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - margin, bounds.size.height);
return inset;

InputTextField *textField=[[InputTextField alloc]init];
textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
[[textField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
}

@end
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm having an issue changing the Border Style and Color of a range of Text Fields within a particular View Controller.  I have a bunch of Text Fields in a view that I want to adjust.  They all have been given the custom class 'InputTextField'.  However the solutions brought up in this thread: [UITextField border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861527/uitextfield-border-color) do not solve my issue.

Here's the Style and Color I'd like to achieve:

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
[[textField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

I've also imported `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h`.  I want to set this so every TextField in my app with the custom class `InputTextField` will appear with this background.  At this point, whenever I run this in the app, the fields all take the background value I've set in Storyboards (currently No Border).

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Have you put this code in the subclass ?

Comment: where are you calling this code in the subclass? if you paste the full subclass code, it'll be easier to figure out.

Comment: @Jkmn - Yes I've added the code into the subclass (within the interface setup of my .m file).  Check the question for the full selection of code.

Comment: @Stas Zhukovskiy - I've added the full section of code above.  Thanks for your help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
```

after

```
return inset;
```

nothing gets called. Move your code above return.

EDIT #1

Add this to your subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    layer.borderWidth = 1;
    layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Sadly that did not fix the problem.  Moving it between the editing RectForBounds section does not affect the fields at all.

Moving it between the RectForBounds section at the top causes a throwback error.

Comment: I also attempted to remove the following line:
    InputTextField *textField=[[InputTextField alloc]init];
in the hopes that it would work since we're already working with the InputTextField however it causes errors with each line.  Defining textField as InputTextField causes errors stating "Property 'layer' not found on object of type 'UITextField'.

Comment: For clarification - I am no longer using a subclass to define other attributes for UITextFields.  So your - (void)layoutSubviews unfortunately does not work when called.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating an `InputTextField` inside a method that just asking you a `CGRect` to draw a rectangle, that already doesn't make much sense but the code will never get called anyway since it's located after the `return` statement.

If you want all your `InputTextField` to look a specific way set the `layer` when the `InputTextField` is instantiated.

Using storyboards that would look like :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
        self.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
        self.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jkmn - this does not work due to the layer property not being found on the VC.

Comment: This code is meant for a class that is subclassing UITextField (the one you wrote `@interface InputTextField : UITextField`).