# how to set UItextfield border color in xcode 6

Tags: xcode6

I've been trying (for weeks) to set uitextfield/view border color in xcode 6 but still not working. I already tried any solutions I found on stackoverflow and other forums too but still not working. I use Objective-C Any help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include at least the state where you are with your code currently, show that you've really done something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField border color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861527/uitextfield-border-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You Need to import Core Graphics File in your implementation file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then use this code to change color of border:

```
 txtPass.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
 txtPass.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

If You want to give border then use

```
 txtPass.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
 txtPass.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

Comment: it's still not working, and I checked but there is no duplicate of UITextField border color. My code is the same as that, I didn't forget to import: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: can you update your question and ahow your code what you have written as this code is working fine on my xcode

Comment: it worked after i did smthing like this. _txtPass.layer.cornerRadius and stuff. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I made it! And thanks a lot guys
[image: I made it]

Comment: please edit your answer to include the code inside the answer, with the proper format.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.