# set color inside textfield near border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to change textfield color not background color but near part of textfield border just like shadow.
As shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5749376/3976183 answer

Comment: Do you have any designer ? ;) 
Just ask him to provide Image and use it in background of TextField, Or try CALayer to create same thing. ` textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
    textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;`

Comment: thanks @Mrug i will handle it with designer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add shadow in `UITextField` as you display in image then the easiest way will be that design image of that `UITextField` and set it to it `UITextField` background.

Answer (score 1):

IT's so simple just slice that image and put that image in Textfield background. or Use the Code suggest by @Mrug.

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius=5.0f; 
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES; 
textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.5f;
```